# System of differential equations with sine and cosine solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Let $x_1^{'} (t) = -x_2(t), x_2^{'} (t) = x_1(t), x_3^{'} (t) = 0$.

I have to solve this system of differential equations. I have the solution but I don't know how to get there. Can you help me ?

The solutions says that as $x_1^{"}(t) = -x_1(t)$, then $x_1 = $A cos t + B sin t and $x_2$ = A sin t - B cos t. My doubt is how we can have solutions in terms of sin t and cos t ?

Comment: Is the missing minus sign in the solution or your transcription? If you correct that to $x_1''+x_1=0$, do you see the harmonic oscillator with the sinusoidal solutions?

Comment: yes it  was minus $x_1$ sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the roots of the characteristic equation are $r_{1, 2} = \lambda \pm \mu i$, then the general solution is, see [*Complex Roots*](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/ComplexRoots.aspx)

$$x(t) = e^{\lambda t}( a \cos \mu t + b \sin \mu t)$$

For your problem, we have

$$\begin{align}x_1' &= -x_2 \\ x_2' &= x_1 \\x_3' &= 0 \end{align}$$

Taking the derivative of the first equation, we have $x_1'' = -x_2'$.

Substituting the second equation, we have

$$x_1'' + x_1 = 0$$

The roots of the characteristic equation are

$$r_{1, 2} = \pm i$$

From the note above, the solution is

$$x_1(t) = A \cos t + B \sin t$$

From $x_2 = -x_1'$, we get

$$x_2(t) = A \sin t - B \cos t$$

From the third equation, we get

$$x_3(t) = C$$